# strings returned by wcf wrapped with extra quotes

Tags: android, wcf, json

I'm stuck with this problem for the last 2 days:

I have server running WCF JSON service that returns type: string.

The client that consumes this service is Android application.

The problem:

The string returned by the WCF service seems to be fine (for example: "result_1"), but the value in the Android application looks like this: ""result_1"" (note the problematic extra quotes...).

What should i do in order to fix this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have had this problem with `iPhone` developers in my workplace. The workaround I used was returning a custom class object instead of `String` like following:

```
public class StringContainer
{
    public String Value { get; set; }
}
```